# cURL get data doesn't update when data on server has changed

Tags: swift, api, curl, background-foreground

I have a function which gets the data from an website api.

```
func getData() {
print("getData is called")
//create authentication ... omitted

//create authentication url and request
let urlPath = "https://...";
let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

//some configuration here...

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: data!)
}
    task.resume()
}
```

I am able to get data from API, and I have an observer so that each time when the app goes to foreground the getData() function can be called again to update the data.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "willEnterForeground", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

func willEnterForeground() {
     print("will enter foreground")
     getData()
}
```

I am pretty sure that when my app goes to foreground, the getData() is called again, however, my data doesn't get updated even when data on the server API has changed. I tried to close the app and open it again, but it still doesn't update the data. So I was wondering if someone can give me some suggestions. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I added some breakpoints in the `let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: data!)
}` and it seems that my code tried to fetch the data (the api changes data every minute), however it got the old data even if I observed that data on server api has changed. If I sent the app to background for a long time (some 15 minutes), when it is brought to foreground, the data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a to make it a closure with a completion. This will enable it to make the request and then call reload "Table View" once you have actually gotten the data back from the request. This is what you need to change on your  `getData()` function

```
func getData(completion: (json) -> Void)) {
     print("getData is called")
     //create authentication url and request
     let urlPath = "https://...";
     let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
     let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
     request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
     request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

     //some configuration here...

     let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           let json = JSON(data: data!)
     }
       completion(json)
}
```

Then you will need to adjust where you call this function because you have changed the parameters it should look more like this.

```
func willEnterForeground() {
    print("will enter foreground")

    getData(completion:{
        self.data = json
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

that will wait till the data is back before it reloads the view updating all your content to reflect what is on the server.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, this doesn't work, I still have the same problem even the getData function is called again when the view didEnterForeground. I used `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` to update the label when the      `session.dataTaskWithURL(url)` completes

Comment: Ahh I just realized you need to make your request a closure with a completion block that way you don't try to reload the data till you actually have it back.

Comment: Could you please explain why you add a completion handler? The `dataTaskWithURL` already uses a completion hander to update the label so the view is updated after the task is completed. As I mentioned in the comments, by adding breakpoints I noticed that my code indeed went to the server to fetch the data and print them in the server, the problem is that the data fetched is not always the latest one. And also I think it should be  `func getData(completion: (json: JSON) -> Void))` and what is  `self.data = json `? I did not have that property. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out it is because I didn't remove the cache. Change the cache policy works then.